# How to restrict user to login if it select the page from the particular directory/folder in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config

I have folder in my asp.net website ..namely admin

i have following pages inside admin folder ... login.aspx, home.aspx, welcome.aspx ...

i want if user directly open page ... welcome.aspx or anyother page inside admin folder then it automatically redirect to login.aspx till they login using admin id and pass ...

how to do this setting in web.config...using authorization vb.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<location>` tag in your web.config:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx

This allows you to specify which folders can only be accessed by which users.  For example to only allow a user named "Admin" and no one else:

```
<location path="/admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="Admin"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```